# Error while adding a column in Access through recordset

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010, recordset, alter

I am trying to add column to an existing table in MS Access 2010 using `adodb.recordset`

```
rst.Open "ALTER TABLE tblPatients ADD COLUMN husband_profession TEXT", conn, adopendynamic, adlockoptimistic
```

I am getting the following error

> ADODB.Recordset error '800a0bb9'
>
> Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are
>   in conflict with one another.

Answer (score 2):

An `ADODB.Recordset` is an object designed to contain records.

An `ALTER TABLE` statement does not return records.

That is the cause of the conflict at `rst.Open` --- you're not giving the `Open` method a valid data source for the `Recordset`.

Assuming your `conn` object variable is a valid open connection, use its `Execute` method to execute your `ALTER TABLE` like this:

```vb
conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblPatients ADD COLUMN husband_profession TEXT"
```

Note the Access SQL `TEXT` type with no size specified will actually give you a memo field when executed from ADO.  If you want a simple text field instead, include a size following the `TEXT` keyword.  The maximum size for an Access text field is 255 characters.  You can substitute a smaller number if you wish.

```vb
conn.Execute "ALTER TABLE tblPatients ADD COLUMN husband_profession TEXT (255)"
```

Comment: Thanks... the issue is sorted out